# Convert posted array of objects back into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

When using jQuery ajax to post the following to an action in a rails controller:

```
$.post('/upload/action',
  {
     show: show,
     slides : [
       { id: 311, position: 1 },
       { id: 312, position: 2 },
       { id: 313, position: 3 }
     ]
  }
)
```

The expectation is that the slides attribute would remain an array but it is being converted into an object.

**Expectation**

`params[:slides]` in the upload/action would return:

```
[
   { id: 311, position: 1 },
   { id: 312, position: 2 },
   { id: 313, position: 3 }
]
```

**Whats actually happening**

`params[:slides]` in the upload/action returns:

`{"0"=>{"id"=>"311", "position"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"312", "position"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"313", "position"=>"3"} }`

---

How is this conversion prevented or undone?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are getting at... if I `$.post( '/upload/action', { show : show, slides : [ 1, 2, 3 ] })` and do `params[:slides]` in the controller/action it returns, as expected, an array. I don't understand why simply having an array of objects forces the containing array of those objects to be converted into an object itself. There has to be a way around this...

Comment: Right, I see the problem. The params are converted to `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, but the indexes remain string, and so you can access via `params[:slides]["0"][:id]`. I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't know a clean way to address this. I would have opted for an array of ids.

Comment: Yes, an array of ids would be more appropriate if I was sending objects with one attribute. However, I am sending an object with many attributes. Added another attribute for clarity.

Comment: You can remap using this: `params[:slides].map!(&:last)`, which would allow `params[:slides][0][:position]`.